# SELECT statement that compares values across multiple tables isn't returning the correct rows

Tags: mysql, select, compare, case

I've searched a number of resources on SO and the web to try and figure out why my MySQL select statement isn't returning the correct rows/results.  I apologize in advance if there's an answer here I missed and appreciate someone pointing it out to me.

A little background.  Assume an email campaign application that has the tables: users, groups, campaigns, queue, managers_groups and settings.  Each group has their own settings that has a flag called 'delivery_enabled' - 1 or 0.  An important note is when a group is managed by another group, the 'managee' group automatically will use the managing group's settings.  Thus , even if the 'managee' group's settings have delivery_enabled set to 1 and their managing group's is set to 0, theirs will also be treated as 0.  I hope I explained that clearly :/

The following statement is used to return rows from the table 'queue' - the queue holds the messages/emails pending delivery by the application.  The statement checks to see if the user's group settings.delivery_enabled = 1 - taking into consideration (via CASE) whether or not we should be using the user's own group settings or their managing group's settings.

```
SELECT 
t1.*
FROM 
queue t1, 
campaigns t2, 
users t3,
managers_groups t4, 
settings t5  
WHERE
( t1.campaign_status = 3 && t1.campaign_id = t2.id && t2.user_id = t3.id && t5.delivery_enabled = 1 ) && 
CASE ( SELECT 1 FROM managers_groups WHERE managee_group_id = t3.group_id )
 WHEN 1 THEN t4.manager_group_id = t5.group_id 
 ELSE t3.group_id = t5.group_id
END
GROUP BY t1.id 
ORDER BY t1.send_at ASC, t1.id ASC
```

The results I'm getting show that a group that has a managing group still uses their own settings and not the managing group's.  I feel like something is wrong with my CASE statement in the WHERE CLAUSE, causing the query to fall-back on the ELSE.

If someone wants to try it out, here's the data I'm using for this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campaigns` (
  `id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `campaigns`
--

INSERT INTO `campaigns` (`id`, `user_id`, `name`) VALUES
(16, 72, 'Steve''s Campaign'),
(13, 83, 'Kelly''s Campaign'),
(14, 77, 'Narek''s Campaign'),
(15, 75, 'Cynthia''s Campaign');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=110 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `groups`
--

INSERT INTO `groups` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(108, 'Managers 002'),
(107, 'Managers 001'),
(106, 'Members 001 - Group B'),
(104, 'Members 002 - Group A'),
(103, 'Members 001 - Group A');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `managers_groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `managers_groups` (
  `id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manager_group_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `managee_group_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=280 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `managers_groups`
--

INSERT INTO `managers_groups` (`id`, `manager_group_id`, `managee_group_id`) VALUES
(274, 108, 104),
(279, 107, 103);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `queue`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `queue` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campaign_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `send_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `queue`
--

INSERT INTO `queue` (`id`, `campaign_id`, `campaign_status`, `send_at`) VALUES
(1, 16, 3, '2012-04-01 20:05:45'),
(2, 16, 3, '2012-04-01 20:05:45'),
(3, 16, 3, '2012-04-01 20:05:45'),
(4, 16, 3, '2012-04-01 20:05:45'),
(5, 15, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:18'),
(6, 15, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:18'),
(7, 15, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:18'),
(8, 15, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:18'),
(9, 15, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:18'),
(10, 15, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:18'),
(11, 15, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:18'),
(12, 14, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:06'),
(13, 14, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:06'),
(14, 14, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:06'),
(15, 14, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:06'),
(16, 14, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:06'),
(17, 14, 3, '2012-04-01 20:00:06'),
(18, 13, 3, '2012-04-01 19:59:53'),
(19, 13, 3, '2012-04-01 19:59:53');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `settings`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (
  `id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `delivery_enabled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `settings`
--

INSERT INTO `settings` (`id`, `group_id`, `delivery_enabled`) VALUES
(19, 107, 1),
(20, 108, 0),
(18, 106, 0),
(16, 104, 1),
(15, 103, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=86 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `group_id`, `username`) VALUES
(83, 106, 'kelly'),
(77, 104, 'narek'),
(75, 104, 'cynthia'),
(72, 103, 'steve');
```

One more note is that I did try a scaled back version with only three tables and far less data which seemed to work fine, but once I used the same methodology in the larger scenario  (which has more tables to reference against) it didn't work.

If more info is needed, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A faster and easier to understand way to handle this would be to just go ahead and left join both settings tables in, and then allow the manager settings to override the individual settings through the use of Coalesce().

```
Select
    queue.*,
    Coalesce(manager_group_settings.delivery_enabled, user_settings.delivery_enabled) As setting_delivery_enabled
From queue
Inner Join campaigns On queue.campaign_id = campaigns.id
Inner Join users On queue.user_id = users.id
Left Outer Join managers_groups On managers_groups.managee_group_id = users.group_id
Left Outer Join settings As user_settings On user_settings.group_id = users.group_id
Left Outer Join settings As manager_group_settings On manager_group_settings.group_id = managers_groups.managee_group_id
Group By queue.id
Order By queue.send_at, queue.id
```

Comment: I haven't tested the code against your tables, so let me know if you see errors. Also notice that I am left joining your managers, and 2 instances of settings. There is a possibility that delivery_enabled would be null if there was neither a user settings or a managing group settings.

Comment: Great approach for this!  When I run the query against the data set (I did remove the lone backslash after the first Inner Join line as it caused an error), I got a "Unknown column 'queue.user_id' in 'on clause'".  I changed the second inner join to 'Inner Join users On campaigns.user_id = users.id' and ran it.  The results are not giving priority to a manager group's settings.  The results show the setting for each own's group regardless of whether they are being managed by another group or not.  Hope I made sense.

Comment: That means that the Left Outer Join of managers_groups is not selecting any rows. Is it possible that there is no data where the managee_group_id is equal to a users' group_id? Maybe I used the wrong columns on that join?

Comment: Only a group that has a manager group will be noted in managers_groups.  If a group does not have a manager group, then there will be no record for that group in the managers_groups.  When a group_id is equal to a managee_group_id there may or may not be data in the tables queue and campaigns.  However, there will always be data in settings for the group_id.

Comment: Can you add manager_group_settings.* and user_settings.* to the select list and tell me what you get?

Comment: When adding those two items in the select, I get the same results as before but between the 3 columns for queue on the right and the 'setting_delivery_enabled' column on the far left, I see the columns for the 'manager_group_settings.*, user_settings.*' part of the query.  One other note is that for rows with the id 18 and 19, all fields for the 'manager_group_settings.*' are NULL.

Comment: Right, so for some reason you don't have a matching group for 18 and 19. Are you absolutely sure there is actually a group in the manager_group_settings for that?

Comment: Records 18 and 19 belong to a campaign that is owned by a user in a group that does not have a managing group - thus they do NOT have a record in the manager_group_settings - they only have one in the users_settings.  Sorry, I think we missed this note in an earlier comment from me.  Groups may or may not have a manager group.

Comment: OK, so then the query is working correctly. It's supposed to override with the manager group, only if it exists, right? So if there's no manager group, it would use the user settings, which AFAICT it is doing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure that you use the coalesced alias column: setting_delivery_enabled when you are checking the value. Don't check anything from an actual table.

Comment: Hi Jordan.  Yes.  You are correct in "It's supposed to override with the manager group, only if it exists, right? So if there's no manager group, it would use the user settings..."  Also, I am checking the setting_enabled_delivery column and it shows that 17 of 19 records as 1 (i.e. true).  So, it's showing 17 records as 'deliverable', when it should only show 4 records given the current values within all the tables.  Moreover, in the setting_delivery_enabled column, there should only be 4 fields with a value of 1.  It appears is not overwriting a user_settings with manager_group_settings.

Comment: I've uploaded an image of the output when running our latest query.  The fields with the red box around them should each be zero. [link](http://i39.tinypic.com/e7z1w2.jpg)

Comment: Derek, look at the data. Both of the delivery_enabled columns are 1 in your actual data. So, you have a data issue. The query is working appropriately.

Comment: Hi Jordan.  I see in the data (the output from your query) that those columns do both have 1 in them.  However, I don't see an issue with the datasets (mysqldump above) I'm using.  Referring to that, notice that Group 108 manages Group 104.  108 has delivery = 0 and 104 has delivery = 1. Because 104 is managed by 108, 104's value for 'setting_delivery_enabled' should be 0.  In the output from your query, it's 1.  Moreover, it doesn't get overwritten with 108's.  Does that make sense?  Or, am I out to lunch? :)  Thanks!

Comment: I got it!  In your last 'On' clause you had `... = managers_groups.managee_group_id`.  It should be `... = managers_groups.manager_group_id`.  I'm going to re-purpose this now to only return the ones where 'setting_delivery_enabled' is 1 and then I should be golden.  So, just to review the changes to your original query, in your second inner join, I changed `queue.user_id` to `campaigns.user.id` and then in the last left outer join, I changed `managers_groups.managee_group_id` to `managers_groups.manager_group_id`.  Thanks for your patience and diligence on this!  Greatly appreciated, Jordan!

Comment: Awesome! Sorry I didn't quite understand the join, but I'm glad you got it :)

Answer (score 0):

From within your CASE statement in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 'has_manager' FROM managers_groups WHERE managee_group_id = t3.group_id )
 WHEN 'has_manager'
```

`'has_manager'` is a string literal. SELECTing it always yields the string literal `'has_manager'`. Thus your CASE statement only ever takes the first branch.

Perhaps you meant `CASE (SELECT has_manager ...) WHEN 1 THEN ...`

Comment: Good catch, Hammerite.  I've made that change and also changed '(SELECT has_manager...' to '(SELECT 1...' since I got a unknown column error.  Running the new query still yields incorrect results.  Using my data set, I get 17 rows returned when there should only be 4.  When I change the 't5.delivery_enabled = 1' to 't5.delivery_enabled = 0', I get all 19 rows from queue when I should only be getting 15.  Strange.  Although not as clean as query as it could be, it still looks like it should work.